# New-MailboxExportRequest By Date Range

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

I am trying to export items out of a mailbox, sent and received between a certain date on Exchange 2016. However the script keeps failing without an error message. Not sure where I am going wrong....

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox "User" -ContentFilter "(Received -lt '02/11/2021') -and (Received -gt '02/15/2021')" -Name User  -FilePath \\server\PSTExport\user.pst
```

Current Script above.

Require both sent and received, which I presume would be changing the received to sent but the date range still doesn't work. Already aware that it seems to hate UK dates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any output at all? Do any exports show when you run`Get-MailboxExportRequest`? What happens when you run the command without a content filter?

Comment: Hello, without a content filter it works fine, but obviously the full mailbox. When I just run Get-MailboxExportRequest it has the request name and says Failed next to it.

Comment: I think you have your conditions the wrong way round. Should it not be `"(Received -gt '02/11/2021') -and (Received -lt '02/15/2021')"`. Since you want it to be after 11th Feb but before 15th Feb?